# Is there any program which will allow me to control volume with mouse buttons?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, mouse, hotkeys

My favorite mouse just died after some four years of hard work and one feature I miss is volume control using mouse buttons. It's driver had that option, but my current mouse's doesn't, so is there any program which will let me assign a mouse button (NOT scrollwheel) to increase or decrease volume in windows (NOT in one of few specific programs)?

**UPDATE**: I can only run series of key presses and mouse button presses with my configuration utility. There doesn't appear to be an option to run a program directly. Would maybe Autohotkey be helpful in this case? I have never used it before, so I don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the free program [X-Mouse Button Control](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm) to remap my mouse buttons. Even though it's very powerful, there is no need to learn scripts to gt it running nicely. It supports Windows 7 in native 64-bit. It has volume control and media features. You can even configure it to change volume only when it's over the taskbar. This screenshot shows the the mousewheel assigned to volume, but that is not necessary: mouse buttons can be used for volume up and volume down.

[image: Media Control screenshot]

Comment: Can you clarify what window you selected in the "Add" button so that it only activates over the taskbar?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Volumouse v1.72 that lets you Control the sound volume with a wheel mouse. And for your case you can add Hot keys (like on the above picture).
[Hotkeys Settings](http://dropmocks.com/mbCJa)

And here the link for the application : 
[Volumouse v1.72](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/volumouse.html).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what mouse you're planning to get, but if its configuration utility allows running custom programs, you can set it to do just about anything with [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html). In specific, these two commands:

```
nircmd.exe changesysvolume  2000
nircmd.exe changesysvolume -2000
```

Comment: Interesting. I think that it does allow me to run programs.

Comment: Alas it does not. Still,the program is very nice and will fill soem other unused hotkeys.

Comment: @AndrejaKo: AutoHotkey will let you do both volume and launch programs.

Comment: @surfasb Thanks! Now I only need to learn how to make scripts...

Comment: You can post on their forum for some help. Provide them the name of the target program your are trying to run and it's path and they can get you started.  As far as interacting with the target program, you'll need to fire up the Window Spy and give them some more info. A longer post always elicits better answers :)